# Como obter uma String de data?

Tags: java, string

Minha dúvida é em relação a como obter uma *string* e manipulá-la. O usuário irá informar dd/mm/aaaa em forma de `String`. Como faço essa captura? E depois preciso transformar essa data em inteiro para que eu possa fazer as validações, como por exemplo se o dia informado não excede 31.

Por exemplo, o usuário irá informar a seguinte `String`: "21/03/2014", e eu preciso obter esta string e passá-la como parâmetro para um método.

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    TAD01 verificacoes = new TAD01();

    String data;
    boolean resultado;

    System.out.print("Informe a data: ");
    data = input.nextLine();

    resultado = verificacoes.converteData(data);
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Obrigado desde já a todos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para parsear uma data, você deve usar a classe [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), e para obter os campos individuais você deve usar a classe [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date data = df.parse("20/02/2015");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(data);

cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);  //retorna o ano
cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); //retorna o mês 
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);  //retorna o dia 1-31
```

Comment: E caso a data passada seja inválida você terá uma java.text.ParseException para tratar.

Answer (score 1):

Se seu objetivo é simplesmente validar você pode usar a classe [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) para tentar analisar a data.

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
// !! Importante !! lenient = false fará com que o parser gere uma exceção caso a data seja inválida. 
// O funcionamento padrão é tentar interpretar a data de algum modo e retornar um objeto date válido. 
// Geralmente isso faz com que a data interpretada seja algo totalmente diferente da data correta.
fmt.setLenient(false); 

String strDate = "31/02/2015"; // uma data inválida

try {
    // caso a data seja inválida, o método parse gerará uma exceção.
    Date date = fmt.parse(strDate);

    // se chegou aqui a data é válida!
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {

    //Data não é válida!
    System.out.println("Data inválida!");
}
```

Veja funcionando no ideone